# React Native Firebase V9.1.1 Order By Date Key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building a chatapp there
And i'm using Firebase Realtime Database and Firebase V9.1.1
How can i ordering the snapshot by the **Date Key**?
There is the look of my DB Structure
As we can see, the data inside DB isn't ordering the date by default
There is the query i tried:

```
onValue(query(ref(db, chatBaseURL), orderByChild('chatDate')), snapshot => console.log(snapshot.val())
```

[image: DB Structure]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you call `snapshot.val()` on the entire result snapshot. This gets you all the results as a JSON object, and the keys in a JSON object have an undefined sort order by definition.

To log the results in the order you requested, loop over the resulting snapshot with `snapshot.forEach()`:

```
onValue(query(ref(db, chatBaseURL), orderByChild('chatDate')), results => 
  results.forEach((snapshot) => {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
  });
});
```